Smoothness of a Function from a Manifold to $\mathbb{R}^{+}$
Let be $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{N}$ a diferentiable manifold.
Show that, if there is $U$ an open set in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ such $X\subseteq U$, then there exists a differentiable  function $\varepsilon:X\to \mathbb{R}^{+}$  so that:
$$\{q\in \mathbb{R}^{N}\mid \exists~ p\in X:d(p,q)<\varepsilon(p)\}\subseteq U$$
Even more, if $(X, \mathscr{T}_{X})$ is compact, then $\varepsilon$ is a constant function.

My attempt:
i) Seems natural to define $\varepsilon$ in the following way. Let be $x\in X$, then $x\in U$ and there exists $r_{x}>0$ such $B(x,r_{x})\subseteq U$. So lets call, $\varepsilon(p):=r_{p}$ this function satisfies the desired. But,how to proof that $\varepsilon$ is differentiable? Seems true by intuition but I have no idea on how to show it.
ii) On the other hand, if $(X, \mathscr{T}_{X})$ is compact, lets consider the open cover $\{B(p,r_{p})\cap X\mid p\in X\}$. Then there exists $Y\subseteq X$ finite such $\{B(p,r_{p})\mid p\in Y\}$ in an open cover of $X$.Calling $C:=\min \{\varepsilon(p)\mid p\in Y\}$ we can redifine the function $\varepsilon$ and now $\varepsilon(p)=C$. In that way, take $q\in \mathbb{R}^{N}$ such $\exists~p\in X:d(p,q)<C$. Also, there is an $s\in Y$ such $p\in B(s,\varepsilon (s))$.
Therefore,
$$d(q,s)\leq d(q,p)+d(p,s)=C+\varepsilon(s)\leq 2\varepsilon (s)$$
So its not clear if $q\in B(s,\varepsilon(s))$ in orden to proof that $q\in U$.
I will appreciate any help.

Maybe tubular neighborhood could assist you?

If you allow just any $r_x$ satisfying $B(x,r_x) \subseteq U$ at each $x$, that won't force $\epsilon$ to even be continuous.

Hint: The function $r_x:= d(x, \mathbb R^N \setminus U)$ is 1-Lipschitz; approximate it from below on $X$ by a positive smooth function.
